# Pagination of a partial with Kaminari in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, partials, kaminari

Here is another Newbie question on Rails 3: I have a model called "Activity". On the show.html.erb page of an activity, I show the comments that belong to this activity as a partial:

```
<%= render :partial => @activity.comments %>
```

How the comments look like is in the _comment.html.erb file.

My question: How can I paginate the comments for an activity with Kaminari?

Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score -1):

Lets assume `params[:page]` is the page number for your comments. You would do something like `@activity.comments.page(params[:page])`. I suggest you read https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari, the README contains pretty much everything you need.

Comment: I read the README and didn't find a solution yet. What I don't understand: Where is the information you usually find in the controller when you use partials? For example, for the pagination of the activities i entered `@activities = Activity.page params[:page]` in the activities_controller, so the view would know which page to display.